# Printing star pattern in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

```
# 
# # #
# # # # #
# # #
#
```

I had constructed the upper half with the following code

```
public void printPattern(int row) {
    int k=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=row; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=(row*2)-1; j++) {
            if(j<=i+k) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        k++;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

But I'm not getting how to construct lower half only with 2 for loops

Comment: If you have the upper half, do you think there is some way to adapt that and change a couple things to produce the bottom half? What about `j` defines the pattern you're making?

Comment: is my answer solved your doubt?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 for loops below your code:

```
int k=0;//initilize k with 0 again 
for(int i=1; i<=row; i++) {
    for(int j=(row*2)-3; j>0;j--) {
        if(j>=i+k) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    k++;
    System.out.println();}
```

Comment: is it necessary to add extra loops for this

Comment: Well adding extra loops wont increase the time Complexity of this code. And if you wants to do with only two loops think in more depth.

Comment: this code is printing consecutive "#" instead 3 and then only 1.

Answer (score 0):

So for a 6 row pattern your code prints out:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
```

At no point do you have something to start decreasing the "#"'s once you hit the half-way mark. Assignments like these try and teach you basic `String` manipulation and loops.

Essentially what you need to do is append "#" for half your rows and then remove the "#" for the remainder, as follows...

```
public void printPattern(int row) {
 String output = "#";
 for(int i = 1; i <= (row / 2) - 1; i++) {
   System.out.println(output);
   output += " #";
 }

 for(int i = 1; i <= (row / 2); i++) {
   System.out.println(output);
   output = output.substring(0, output.lastIndexOf("#")).trim();
 }
}
```

Comment: what I'm trying is to print # directly not thinking of replacing them

Comment: @MattJoshi, well you not replacing them, your just removing them from your String. Did you come right? If so, please mark this question as resolved. Tx

Answer (score 0):

You can write the full code inside two for loops, as

```
    public void printPattern(int row) {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
            boolean isFirstHalf = (i <= (row + 1) / 2);
            int noOfHashToPrint = (isFirstHalf) ? (2 * (i-1))+1 : (2 * (row-i) + 1);
            for (j = 1; j <= noOfHashToPrint; j++)
                System.out.print("#");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is simple function to work on that,

```
public void printPattern(int row) {
int k=0;
for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {

    for(int j=0; j<=k; j++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        k++;
    System.out.println();
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] value = new char[5];
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i< 5;i++) {
    value[j]='#';
    System.out.println(value);
    if(i<2) {
    value[j+1] ='#';
    value[j+2] ='#';
    j=j+2;

    }
    else {
        if(j != 0) {
        value[j]=' ';
        value[j-1]=' ';
        j=j-2;

        }

    }
}
```